# Why does TypeScript's Structural Typing (i.e. "Duck Typing") necessitate non-strict Type Unions?

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, discriminated-union

Assume that the following types are defined:

```
type A = {
  a: string,
}

type B = {
  a: number,
  b: number,
}
```

These two assignments produce an error:

```
// Not assignable to A because 'b' doesn't exist on A
const x: A = {
  a: 'hello',
  b: 10
}

// Not assignable to B because 'a' expects type 'string'
const x: B = {
  a: 'hello',
  b: 10
}
```

TypeScript's documentation defines a Union Type as:

> A union type is a type formed from two or more other types, representing values that may be any one of those types.

Based on this, I would have expected the following declaration to produce an error:

```
const x: A | B = {
  a: 'hello',
  b: 10
}
```

But it doesn't. The object literally is not assignable to type `A` and it's not assignable to type `B`, yet it *is* assignable to `A | B`.

How can I think of Type Unions in a way that makes this result make sense?

Editing: Of course, I search for half the day and can't find information that documents this, but as soon as I post, I find a number of other posts here talking about the same thing.

From what I found, an object literal can have excess properties when assigned as a Type Union, as long as one of the members has that property.

If I understand correctly, my object literal satisfies type `A`, with the property `b` being an excess property, which is allowed because another member of the union (`B`) includes the property.

Why does TypeScript's Structural Typing (i.e. "Duck Typing") necessitate non-strict Type Unions? From the number of SO posts I'm seeing relating to this, it seems like most people expect a Type Union to be strict. I'm sure that there's a compelling reason for non-strict unions to be the default, can someone provide some intuition for why that's the case?

Comment: Interesting....and you can't access `a.b`, only `x.a` — and then only the functions of `a` that are common to both `number` and `string`, like `x.a.toString()`.

Comment: Pretty easy to get a crash here, too: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAglC8UDeAoKUCGAuKBnYATgJYB2A5gDQoC+KKokUAQgsmpjiQK4C2ARhAJV0fTrwFCadAMYB7EvigAPHHAA+zVqnTYoAcgAWEADbHZe4VFFQAjAAYpKIgDMoACj189UUsoCUyFAA9EFQJBgEBLIA7lDARlAAbhjGXNBKcbJx4NBM7OhKAHQYhcCyAGJEShAAJm4BIVDSBBi4BgCEKI1QAHoA-DRAA

Comment: Also "Not assignable to A because 'b' doesn't exist on A" isn't totally right.
It's just not _directly_ assignable https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAglC8UDeAoKUCGAuKBnYATgJYB2A5gDQoC+KKokUAQgsmpjiQK4C2ARhAJV0fTrwFCadAMYB7EvigAPGABUIPMK1TpsUAOQALCABsTs-cKiioARgAMUuQuDKYOOIhXrNQA.

Comment: FWIW [ms/TS#14094](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/14094) was the (eventually declined) suggestion to have an "exclusive union" operator, and [ms/TS#20863](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/20863) is the (still open) suggestion to perform excess property checks on all unions as opposed to jut *discriminated* unions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From a type theory perspective, TypeScript uses structural typing ("if it acts like a duck, it's a duck") and allows additional properties.  As a result:

```
const x = {
  a: 'hello',
  b: 10
}
function doSomethingWithA(a: A) {}
// Works: x has shape type A = { a: string }
doSomethingWithA(x);
// Also works: Same reason
const y: A = x;
```

Your `A | B` assignment works for similar reasons:

```
// Works: has shape { a: string } | { a: number, b: number }
const x: A | B = {
  a: 'hello',
  b: 10
}
```

TypeScript has additional handling for the specific case of object literals with an explicit type defined: since that's a common potential source of errors, it raises errors for that specific case.  See [Microsoft/TypeScript/#3755](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/3755), which offers this more in-depth explanation from Anders Hejlsberg for the rationale:

> An interesting fact about object literals (and array literals) is that an object reference produced by a literal is known to be the only reference to that object. Thus, when an object literal is assigned to a variable or passed for a parameter of a type with fewer properties than the object literal, we know that information is irretrievably lost. This is a strong indication that something is wrong--probably stronger than the benefits afforded by allowing it.

There's a popular feature request for [exact types](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/12936), which could help enforce all of this more strictly, but it has not been implemented.

Now, if I understand correctly, TypeScript could extend its "not assignable" special case from Microsoft/TypeScript/#3755 to union literals: it presumably hasn't due to some combination of lack of demand, implementation complexity, or compiler performance hit. (I haven't searched GitHub issues to see if this has been requested.)